# Audio problems in ubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound

"My question is about how to enable audio on ubuntu studio 20.10."

I use an hdmi connected device with speakers as my display, through nvidia 1050TI graphics card.

The same device works flawlessly when i boot into windows....

Comment: Do you have "alsa-utils" and "pulseaudio" installed?

Comment: Have you checked you are using the right device in audio settings?